# How do I make an Infinitely Generated Game Map in BGE using Cloud Texture?

Tags: python, modifiers, game-engine, logic-bricks

I am making a Blender game with a map that is procedurally generated and infinite.

With the way I am designing this game the player can travel for infinity but still get back to their original location.

The way I plan on doing this is by having a plane parented to the player that has a displace modifier and a cloud texture.

When the player moves so does the plane. When the plane gets further from the starting location it gets further from the empty which controls the texture coordinates of the displace modifier.

This should allow the player to walk in any direction infinitely because the texture never ends. My only problem, however, is that while the plane is parented to the player just fine, the displace modifier does not update with the movement.

It took me a long time to figure out how to constrain the rotation and location of the plane which I did using a vertex parent.

Now I just need to figure out how to make the displace modifier work in-game.

I've heard that most modifiers are not supported in the game engine, but is there a way to force the modifier to update with a python script, or to replace the modifier with something else that works the same way?

I plan on turning this game into a zombie game that is infinite but first I need to get this one problem fixed. Any help would be greatly appreciated! ;)

[Link to get Game](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5LVYjOK5wy6dWduaVJzSmNNNVU)

Comment: A cloud texture is a repeating pattern right? Then it wouldn't make much sense to use it. Your world would become very boring.

Comment: Okay. I guess I might try out another texture but the main thing I'm focusing on right now is the displacement modifier. I need that to work in order for my game to actually work. Do you have any ideas on how to get that working?

Comment: I'm still pretty new to python. These kind of things always impress me when they work, but I don't know anything about them. I'm only pretty good at programming physics for like planes and stuff.

Comment: Well, thanks anyway! ;) I always appreciate a good critique. Looking at the game now, when moving the plane in the viewport (not the game) I can see that it would be very repetitive. Maybe I can add mountains, rocks, houses, ZOMBIES, etc, once I get this whole terrain thing figured out. I just hope that this is possible because my current build of my game which I am going to merge with these mechanics is kind of boring!

Here's a link to the other current game in which I am going to impliment this infinite terrain into: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5LVYjOK5wy6TGV4ZzZ0V0NFczA

Comment: I have the same problem with making my games exciting. I'm a bad map designer XD.

Comment: Lol! Me too. Plus my biggest concern is having a linear and boring game. I obviously dont want to model an infinite game map or cheat by using preset land pieces and spawning them in with spawners. To me that looks way too repetetive and takes forever to do the logic bricks. If you download my blend file and move the character you may see what im hoping to acomplish. More variation will be added, later though.