# BGE Infinite Plane?

Tags: game-engine

I am making an open world game (a game in which players can explore the world, rather than following a set list of events). I've tried making a plane very large, but of course, it is still finite and when I zoom out, it doesn't completely render.

How would I make an infinite plane in the Blender Game Engine?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17877/how-do-you-create-an-infinite-ground-plane and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63033/how-to-create-an-infinite-plane-in-cycles or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88166/how-do-i-make-an-infinitely-generated-game-map-in-bge-using-cloud-texture

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Most of these are for Blender/Blender Cycles. The only one for BGE is unanswered.

Comment: @anonymous I do not think it is possible, in fact what the previous comment says has no link with bge, what gave me the most result is to make a procedural system of land construction, while advancing the seed is adding planes continuously randomly from there I call it procedural in parentheses because to make sense of the terrenu tube I do a script that indicates which plane fits with that plane so that the textures have a smooth and coherent transition