# How can I make a plane look infinite?

Tags: camera, scene

Im trying to make a forest scene of a path and I want it to seem like the path is infinite or the path goes on for a very long time.  Im gonna also add trees to the side of the path and an HDRI for the sky.  I wanna know what I should set the camera settings and the plane size to so that the screen will be filled but appear to be infinite.  All help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63033/how-to-create-an-infinite-plane-in-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17877/how-do-you-create-an-infinite-ground-plane or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98855/bge-infinite-plane

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos second link helped, thank you.

Comment: If you could provide an example image of the type of effect you are trying to achieve it might help people give more specific guidance.

Comment: Heres some pictures to help others out https://imgur.com/a/t2nzO